# How can I fix the wierd shape glitch of the curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers

So I was trying to make a robot with wirings and pipes.
[image: This is what happened.]

But it turned out it resulted in the formation of this horrifying worm-like thingy.
Note: I used the TubeTool addon to add pipes between faces.
Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: This may be because the tube you are deforming is not straight along one axis.

Comment: Origin is at the global center and  the axis are all straight. Still it didn't work.

Comment: Did you apply the rotation?

Comment: Yup.  But still doesn't work.
Here is the blend file: [Zerobot](https://pasteall.org/media/7/a/7ac34aa183dffba2a3a751e604a3e9a6.blend)

Comment: Ok.. will have a look